# Encryption ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

Tags: python, encryption, base64, valueerror

I am trying to encrypt a string which will be decrypted later for a password function.

However, when i am trying to encrypt it, I got an error saying that the input string must be a multiple of 16 in length.

This is my encryption code, which uses the library Jasypt2Python.

```
def test_basic_encryption(self):
        try:
            self.ciphertext = "encrypt123"
            self.j2p = J2PEngine(self.ciphertext)
            given_ciphertext = self.j2p.encrypt('mypw123.')
        except Exception:
            e_str = traceback.format_exc()
            print(e_str)
```

Any idea how to solve this or to make my password a multiple of 16 in length ?

Comment: Maybe it expects you to pad the length to a multiple of 16?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am asking in my question. I have no idea how to pad it. But I have tried putting my string to be 16 characters manually but still got the same error.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for the J2PEngine class?

Comment: https://github.com/Telmediq/jasypt-2-python

Comment: Are you sure that's the one you're using?  The `encrypt()` function is completely commented out.

Comment: I uncommented the encrypt function. Forgot to inform you sorry

Comment: If the author commented it out, there must have been a good reason.  Why do you expect the code to work?  That's a bit like taking a light bulb out of the trash and complaining that it won't light up.

Comment: In any case, I played with it a bit and it won't run for me because the module has several other dependencies that I don't want to install.  I think you're on your own -- good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Most symmetric ciphers such as AES work as so called block ciphers. They encrypt the data „block by block“. Modern algorithms use 128 bit blocks — 16 bytes.

To pad the data means for example to expand the string „hello“ (5 bytes ASCII) to 16 bytes. One possibility is to add 11 bytes each with the value 11. if you decrypt the data you will have to look at the last byte (11) and remove this number of bytes from the end. If your text already is a multiple of 16 add a new block only with padding (each byte of value 16).

Look up „PKCS5 padding“ for the spec.